# Why doesn't the code enter each block?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to select all the check boxes, that are checked and then get the value of `id` attribute.

I am doing the following way :

```
 $("input:checkbox[class=selectioncheckbox]").each(function() {
        console.log("Inside each block");
        if($(this).is(":checked")) {
             console.log("Inside if block");
             pnames[c] = $(this).attr('id');  
             console.log(pnames[c] + " " + c);
             c++;
        } 
   });
```

But there is a problem. The code never enters the `each` block. What could be the reason for this?

EDIT:
Here is the code that adds checkboxes with class `selectioncheckbox`:

```
$('#teamcheckbox_a').change(function() {
                           if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                               $('#teamcheckbox_b').prop('checked',false);
                                $('#playerselect').empty();
                                team_a = $('#teamnames_a option:selected').text(); 
                                $.ajax( {
                                    url : 'http://localhost:8081/Football/GetPlayerNames',
                                    data : {
                                       teamname : $('#teamnames_a option:selected').text() 
                                    },
                                    dataType : 'json',
                                    type : 'GET'
                                })
                                .done(function(message) {
                                      $('#playerselect').html("<label>Select Players</label>");
                                      $.each(message,function(index,row) {
                                          $('#playerselect').append(
                                                         "<tr>" + 
                                                         "<td class='text-center'>" + row.jnumber +  "</td>" + 
                                                         "<td>" + row.name + "</td>" +  
                                                         "<td class='text-center'>" + row.position + "</td>" +
                                                         "<td> <input type='checkbox' class='selectioncheckbox form-control input-lg' id='" + row.jnumber + ":" + row.name + "' /> </td>" +
                                                         "</tr>");
                                      });
                                       $('.selectioncheckbox').change(function() {
                                              if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                                  count++;
                                              } else {
                                                  count--;
                                              }
                                              $('#pcount').html("Count : " + count);
                                      });
                                })
                                .fail(function(message) {
                                      console.log(message);
                                })
                           }
                       });

                       $('#teamcheckbox_b').change(function() {
                         if($(this).is(':checked') ) {
                                $('#teamcheckbox_a').prop('checked',false);
                                $('#playerselect').empty();
                                team_a = $('#teamnames_b option:selected').text(); 
                                $.ajax( {
                                    url : 'http://localhost:8081/Football/GetPlayerNames',
                                    data : {
                                       teamname : $('#teamnames_b option:selected').text() 
                                    },
                                    dataType : 'json',
                                    type : 'GET'
                                })
                                .done(function(message) {
                                      $('#playerselect').html("<label>Select Players</label>");
                                      $.each(message,function(index,row) {
                                          $('#playerselect').append(
                                                         "<tr>" + 
                                                         "<td class='text-center'>" + row.jnumber +  "</td>" + 
                                                         "<td>" + row.name + "</td>" +  
                                                         "<td class='text-center'>" + row.position + "</td>" +
                                                         "<td> <input type='checkbox' class='selectioncheckbox form-control input-lg' id='" + row.jnumber + ":" + row.name + "' /> </td>" +
                                                         "</tr>");
                                      });
                                       $('.selectioncheckbox').change(function() {
                                              if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                                                  count++;
                                              } else {
                                                  count--;
                                              }
                                              $('#pcount').html("Count : " + count);
                                      });
                                })
                                .fail(function(message) {
                                      console.log(message);
                                })
                         }
                       });
```

Comment: It happens because nothing found with this selector. Are you sure it shouldn't be `$('input.selectioncheckbox[type=checkbox]')`?

Comment: Try `$(".selectioncheckbox:checked").each(function () {`

Comment: Your document has no elements that match the selector `input:checkbox[class=selectioncheckbox]` at the time the `$(...)` call is made. Can you provide a small self-contained example (with both JavaScript *and* HTML) that produces your problem?

Comment: Without seeing any relevant HTML markup, how can we help???

Comment: Use as selector: `$("input.selectioncheckbox:checked")` because i guess `selectioncheckbox` is only applied to checkboxes and no need to check for `checked` state inside `each loop`

Comment: @SuhailGupta So ya `[class=selectioncheckbox]` fails because more than one class set, use class selector, not attribute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the code isn't being called at all, or `$("input:checkbox[class=selectioncheckbox]")` has a length of `0` (which is most likely caused by running the code before the elements have been added to the DOM, in which case you can resolve it with a ready handler).

Comment: Yes, the checkboxes are added after the page is loaded with the ajax call.

Comment: *"which is most likely caused by..."* Or having another class on the relevant element.

Comment: This answer is technically correct, but the problem is that his selector makes no sense, as pointed out in the comments on the question.

Comment: @EdCottrell It could make sense but i'm quite sure here it doesn't

Comment: @SuhailGupta If more than one class set on same element: `[class=selectioncheckbox]` would failed. Why don't you use class selector?

Comment: @A.Wolff The `:checkbox` part never makes sense.

Comment: @EdCottrell — What doesn't make sense about it? https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/

Comment: @A.Wolff It could be that the OP has other elements with this class but wants to select elements with *only* this class. (**could**)..

Comment: @Quentin I stand corrected. Somehow, I never knew that was a thing. Oops!

Comment: @George Ya exactly my thought but sure it isn't :)

Answer (score 1):

Use as selector: `$(".selectioncheckbox:checked")` because i guess selectioncheckbox is only applied to checkboxes and no need to check for checked state inside each loop.

And your issue was none element was matched because using attribute selector `[class=selectioncheckbox]` if more than one class set on same element, this doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

The script is calling before the elements added to the DOM. So the script is unable to identify the class name and the length will be 0. Call the script in the ready handler as follows.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     var c= 0;
     var pnames = [];
     $("input:checkbox[class=selectioncheckbox]").each(function() {
            console.log("Inside each block");
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {
                 console.log("Inside if block");
                 pnames[c] = $(this).attr('id');  
                 console.log(pnames[c] + " " + c);
                 c++;
            } 
      });
});
```